# Is this break statement valid in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, break

I have a function which selects a text based on the input string. If both matches i make it selected. PFb the function,

```
function setDropdownTextContains(dropdownId,selectedValue,hfId){
            $('#'+dropdownId+' option').each(function(){

                     if($(this).text() === selectedValue){
                         $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                         break;
                     }
            });
                 $('#'+hfId).val("ModelName doesnt match");
        }
```

I get the below error `unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch` ... What am i doing wrong??

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. Your `break` is not in a loop or `switch`. Return `false` to stop the `.each` loop.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The exception text is quite descriptive. You really can't use `break` statement inside `if` clause. In your case you should use `return false` to stop the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) iteration.

Answer (score 4):

A `break` statement is designed to end a `for, while or do-while` loop or a switch statement. It has no side effects where you are using it. What are you trying to achieve?

In your specific case, just `return false`

Answer (score 2):

`$().each` is a function method, so you will terminate it with `return`

```
function setDropdownTextContains(dropdownId,selectedValue,hfId){
    $('#'+dropdownId+' option').each(function(){   
         if($(this).text() === selectedValue){
             $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
             return false; // <--
         }
    });
    $('#'+hfId).val("ModelName doesnt match");
}
```

Comment: Nope, `return` won't stop the iteration. It should return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

to break you could just `return false;`, like

```
if($(this).text() === selectedValue){
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    return false;
}
```

> Returning 'false' from within the each function completely stops the
>   loop through all of the elements (this is like using a 'break' with a
>   normal loop). Returning 'true' from within the loop skips to the next
>   iteration (this is like using a 'continue' with a normal loop)

Answer (score 1):

As per jQuery documentation, break is to break out of the loop. You cannot use it inside if statement.

You can use `return false` instead.

```
jQuery.each(arr, function() {
      $("#" + this).text("Mine is " + this + ".");
       return (this != "three"); // will stop running after "three"
   });
```